How to design this shape?
the model is available for free here:
https://makerworld.com/en/models/13717#profileId-13429
The cylinder part of the base could be created using 2 coils to create the edges and loft them together, then circular pattern the single fin, flip and repeat; but how to close out the top into a dome?




This is a very specific design question, not related to 3D printing, I think this should fit Blender.SE much better.
